# How to use events for programmatically added controls in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, events, controls

I am dynamically adding labels in a tabPage and I want to use events for those labels, for example:

```
foreach(Label l in tabPage1.Controls)
{
    if(l.Click)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

but that is clearly not the way to do it since the event 'Control.Click' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= .
Any ideas how I might do this?

Comment: Scroll down to the related links at the bottom right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to create a method for handling the event

```
foreach(Label l in tabPage1.Controls)
{
    l.Click += MyClickHandler;
}



...


void MyClickHandler(object sender, EventArg e)
{
    Label l = (Label) sender;
    //do something
}
```